# Apply style to pdf downloaded using jsPdf

Tags: javascript, css, jspdf

I am using *jsPdf* plugin, that allows to download the contents of a `div`. But I am having hard time with the styling of the contents.

Although I can see the expected style, when viewed in the browser, but **not** when I download.

***Note***: I have used inline style, so as to apply the CSS properties on PDF, assuming that the browser CSS won't be available to PDF.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o9x7ptzq/).

Try to download the pdf, and see that none of the style has been applied.

Comment: bad idea to split newline to parse dom. you are using jQuery, so use it, it`s simple to manipulate dom objects. for a test you can put `document.body.innerHTML = newPdfDiv.innerHTML;` before `pdf.fromHTML` to see what you created in browser;

Comment: Here's a [community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) on requesting urgency.

Comment: I am not sure why you are adding p elements. As I can see by `console.log`ging  your html that is sent to jsPDF, all of your styles are applied on empty elements, giving no styles. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/o9x7ptzq/1/